# Splitting column values by field value in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to separate the values in a column in R. I went through this article, but it does not give name of the column according to the splitted value.
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html

My column value is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c("['78', '79', '80', '98']", 
"['1', '78', '80']"))
colnames(df) <- c("list")
```

Required Output:

| val_1 | val_78 | val_79 | val_80 | val_98 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please add data with `dput(head(df,n))`?

Comment: yeah.. just a moment

Comment: I have done it as you have requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of options both of which require cleaning of the column by removing values like `[]'` in the text.

1. Using `splitstackshape::cSplit_e`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(val = gsub("\\[|\\]|'", "", val)) %>%
  splitstackshape::cSplit_e('val', sep = ',\\s', fixed = FALSE, 
                            type = 'character', fill = 0, drop = TRUE)

#  val_1 val_78 val_79 val_80 val_98
#1     0      1      1      1      1
#2     1      1      0      1      0
```

2. `tidyverse` -

```
df %>%
  mutate(val = gsub("\\[|\\]|'", "", val)) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(val, sep = ',\\s+') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = val, values_from = val, values_fn = length, 
              values_fill = 0, names_prefix = 'val_') %>%
  select(-row)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(val = c("['78', '79', '80', '98']","['1', '78', '80']"))
```